# Inverse of $\tanh^{\prime\prime}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

I have problems finding the inverse function of the second derivative of the hyperbolic tangent. I know it is not invertible on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, but having a closed form for the inverse on, lets say, $[-0.5,0.5]$ would be enough for me. Any help or references appreciated.
$$\tanh^{\prime\prime}(x)=-2\tanh(x)\mathop{\rm sech}\nolimits^2 (x) 
.$$

Comment: There should be a $2$ between the $-$ and $\tanh(x)\text{sech}^2 (x)$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Even though I gladly take the inverse of 1/2 tanh'' as well :)

Comment: Writing out the definitions gives a cubic equation in $e^{2x}$...

Comment: WolframAlpha gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+function+of+-2Tanh%5Bx%5DSech%5Bx%5D%5E2) quite ugly result in terms of radicals and $\text{arsech}$.

Comment: Thank you all. It helps a lot to know that it is such a complicated expression, now I can move on :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to exponential form and plugging into Mathematica yields the three inverse functions

$
\frac{1}{2} \log \left(-\frac{-72 y-64}{6 y
   \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}-\frac{3 y+8}{3 y}+\frac{2
   \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}{3 y}\right) $

$
\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) (-72 y-64)}{12 y \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3
   \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}-\frac{3 y+8}{3 y}-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}{3 y}\right)
$

$
\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) (-72 y-64)}{12 y \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3
   \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}-\frac{3 y+8}{3 y}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{-27 y^2-108 y+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 y^4-16 y^2}-64}}{3 y}\right)
$

which graphically seem to be correct for various ranges of $y$; no one of those inverses seems perfect for your desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\text{sech}^2(x)=1-\tanh^2(x)$, it can be seen that an equivalent expression for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\tanh(x)$ is $2\left(\tanh^3(x)-\tanh(x)\right)$, so solving the equation $y=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\tanh(x)$ with $y\in\mathbb R$ amounts to solving the cubic
$$\frac{y}{2}=t^3-t$$
and then applying $\tanh^{-1}$ to $t$. We can solve the cubic with [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).